# Perfect JSON structure

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I've been looking around and learning `JSON` a little bit. I thought it would be good to start learning with something easy but it seems it is not. I am trying to do `JSON` database. For example it has brand names and every brand has its own products with some info. I've done that like this which is actually much longer:

```
{
  "Snuses": {
    "Brands": {
      "CATCH": [
        {
          "Products": "CATCH EUCALYPTUS WHITE LARGE",
          "nicotine": "8.0"
        }
      ]
}
```

Now I am using **Firebase** to parse the "Brands" like "CATCH" etc.. But I can't.

In swift I am trying to do it like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").child("Brands")

        self.ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot -> Void in
            for brands in snapshot.children {
                print(brands)
            }
        })

    })
}
```

How to get reference to the Brands first? And how to store list of brands separately?

Some smart guys told me that it is not correct to do but I don't know what is wrong with the `JSON` structure. How can I flatten it?

I red the docs also that says how it is best to do it but it is a little to complicaetd. Can you point me to the right direction?

Comment: means you want all brand names seperately????

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 I actually do not know. That's why I am confused. One guy in the Chat told me I have to do this and I didn't understand it and that's why I asked here.

Comment: can you explain what you actually want to do ... so I can help you

Comment: First I am trying to get the Brand names from the JSON file and put them into tableView. After, lets say CATCH is pressed I want to show "Products" those which belongs to the CATCH Brand. I am taking it slow to learn so that is the first thing I want to do. I've never done anything with networking before that's why it is so complicated to me.

Comment: ok ... so there are variety of brands and all brands have different child ... so you want to add brandnames in tableview and click on that you want its all products ... Am I right????

Comment: Yes. Totally right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118804/discussion-between-ei-captain-v2-0-and-tarvo-maesepp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do `allKeys` to get allKeys from snap

```
   let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").child("Brands")

    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            if let allProducts = (snapshot.value?.allKeys)! as? [String]{
                self.snusBrandsArray = allProducts                      
                self.productstable.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
```